# Array sort by First Value

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

This is my current Array

```
Array
(
    [0] => [10,13],
    [1] => [11,15],
    [2] => [12,7],
    [3] => [1,0],
    [4] => [2,0],
    [5] => [3,0],
    [6] => [4,0],
    [7] => [5,0],
    [8] => [6,0],
    [9] => [7,0],
    [10] => [8,0],
    [11] => [9,0]
);
```

I want to sort this array by the value(value before comma).
Result should be like this:

```
Array
(    
    [1] => [1,0],
    [2] => [2,0],
    [3] => [3,0],
    [4] => [4,0],
    [5] => [5,0],
    [6] => [6,0],
    [7] => [7,0],
    [8] => [8,0],
    [9] => [9,0],
    [10] => [10,13],
    [11] => [11,15],
    [12] => [12,7]
);
```

Is it possible in PHP ?

Comment: Its possible you need a loop that compares the value, this is quite simple. If you google this there should be TONS of answers for this .. Array sorting

Comment: 1. `usort` 2. Does the second array have to start with index `1`?

Comment: @LJ-C: Well ! Thank you for your comment but if I searched it successfully why should I post here ?

Comment: Might be rhetorical, but the brackets are making me ask...are your array values dealing with other arrays (multidimensional arrays) or plain string values?

Comment: @Crackertastic: Thanks for comment. This is not a multidimensioal array it just a string.

Comment: @GoogleUser I've posted an answer tailored to strings.  (e.g. `[1,0]` is really `"[1,0]"`)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**OPTION 1 : IF TWO DIMENSIONAL ARRAY TRY THIS ONE**

```
$data = array();
$data[0] = array(10, 13);
$data[2] = array(11, 15);
$data[3] = array(12, 7);
$data[4] = array(1, 0);
$data[5] = array(2, 0);
$data[6] = array(3, 0);
$data[7] = array(4, 0);
$data[8] = array(5, 0);
$data[9] = array(6, 0);
$data[10] = array(7, 0);
$data[11] = array(8, 0);
$data[12] = array(9, 0);


echo "<pre>";
//print_r($data);
array_multisort($data);
print_r($data);
echo "</pre>";
?>
```

OUTPUT

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => 1
        [1] => 0
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => 2
        [1] => 0
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => 3
        [1] => 0
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [0] => 4
        [1] => 0
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [0] => 5
        [1] => 0
    )

[5] => Array
    (
        [0] => 6
        [1] => 0
    )

[6] => Array
    (
        [0] => 7
        [1] => 0
    )

[7] => Array
    (
        [0] => 8
        [1] => 0
    )

[8] => Array
    (
        [0] => 9
        [1] => 0
    )

[9] => Array
    (
        [0] => 10
        [1] => 13
    )

[10] => Array
    (
        [0] => 11
        [1] => 15
    )

[11] => Array
    (
        [0] => 12
        [1] => 7
    )
)
```

**OPTION 2 : IF ONE DIMENSIONAL ARRAY TRY THIS ONE**

```
$data = array();
$data[0] = "10,13";
$data[2] = "11,15";
$data[3] = "12,7";
$data[4] = "1,0";
$data[5] = "2,0";
$data[6] = "3,0";
$data[7] = "4,0";
$data[8] = "5,0";
$data[9] = "6,0";
$data[10] = "7,0";
$data[11] = "8,0";
$data[12] = "9,0";

echo "<pre>";
//print_r($data);
echo "</pre>";

function dataSort($data){
    $data_temp =array();
    foreach($data as $item){
        $data_temp[] = explode(",",$item);
    }
    array_multisort($data_temp);

    $data =array();
    foreach($data_temp as $item){
        $data[] = $item[0].",".$item[1];
    }
    return $data;
}
$data  = dataSort($data); 
print_r($data);
```

OUTPUT

```
Array
(
   [0] => 1,0
   [1] => 2,0
   [2] => 3,0
   [3] => 4,0
   [4] => 5,0
   [5] => 6,0
   [6] => 7,0
   [7] => 8,0
   [8] => 9,0
   [9] => 10,13
   [10] => 11,15
   [11] => 12,7
)
```

Comment: It just change the first value Array
(
    [0] => [1,0],
    [1] => [10,13],
    [2] => [11,15],
    [3] => [12,7],
    [4] => [2,0],
    [5] => [3,0],
    [6] => [4,0],
    [7] => [5,0],
    [8] => [6,0],
    [9] => [7,0],
    [10] => [8,0],
    [11] => [9,0]
)

Comment: I have added two options, for single dimensional and two multi dimensional array.....

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
function mSort($a,$b) {
    if ($a[0] == $b[0]) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a[0] < $b[0]) ? -1 : 1;
}

usort($arr, "mSort");

print_r($arr);
```

Answer (score 2):

You may use usort() function or any of [this list](http://www.php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php), what's near to you. For example:

```
<?php

$array = array (
    array(10,13),
    array(11,15),
    array(12,7),
    array(1,0),
    array(2,0),
    array(3,0),
    array(4,0),
    array(5,0),
    array(6,0),
    array(7,0),
    array(8,0),
    array(9,0)
);

function mySort( $l, $r ) {
   return (( $l[0] == $r[0] ) ? 0 : ($l[0] > $r[0] ? 1 : -1) );
}

usort( $array, 'mySort' );

print_r( $array );

?>
```

[demo](http://codepad.org/QTm1jVTd)

Comment: I posted same answer before him :)

Answer (score 1):

This is What you want [DEMO](http://codepad.org/3AW5xic6)

```
 <?php


$yourArray = array(
    1 => array(
        10,
        13
    ),
    2 => array(
        11,
        15
    ),
    3 => array(
        12,
        7
    ),
    4 => array(
        1,
        0
    ),
    5 => array(
        2,
        0
    ),
    6 => array(
        3,
        0
    ),
    7 => array(
        4,
        0
    ),
    8 => array(
        5,
        0
    ),
    9 => array(
        6,
        0
    ),
    10 => array(
        7,
        0
    ),
    11 => array(
        8,
        0
    ),
    12 => array(
        9,
        0
    )
);

$array = array();

foreach ($yourArray as $key => $row) {
    $array[$key] = $yourArray['value'];
}
array_multisort($array, SORT_DESC, $yourArray);

$yourArray = array_combine(range(1, count($yourArray)), array_values($yourArray));

print_r($yourArray);

?>
```

Comment: It just change the first value Array
(
    [0] => [1,0],
    [1] => [10,13],
    [2] => [11,15],
    [3] => [12,7],
    [4] => [2,0],
    [5] => [3,0],
    [6] => [4,0],
    [7] => [5,0],
    [8] => [6,0],
    [9] => [7,0],
    [10] => [8,0],
    [11] => [9,0],
)

Comment: you mean you want to remaining the key as your output ?

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
$new = array();
foreach($first_array as $key => $value) {
     $new[$key] = $value;
 }
array_multisort($new, SORT_ASC, $first_array);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to access `$value` as a reference to the entry in `$array`:

```
private function orderByKey(&$array) {
    ksort($array);
    foreach($array as &$value) {
        if (is_array($value)) {
            $this->orderByKey($value);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use array_multisort() function for this

```
$arr = array([10,13],[11,15],[12,7],[1,0],[2,0],[3,0],[4,0],[5,0],[6,0],[7,0],[8,0],[9,0]);

        array_multisort($arr);
        var_dump($arr);exit;
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the values you are dealing with are strings (per your response to my comment) you need to isolate the first numerical value, then sort based on that.  (Please note this does not support multiples of the same "first number").

Example:

```
$a = array("[1,10]", "[2,19]", "[6,13]", "[2,15]", "[4,16]");

$sortable = array();

foreach($a as $subject) {
    $start = strpos($subject, "[");
    $end = strpos($subject, ",");
    $ndx = substr($subject, $start, $end - $start);
    $sortable[$ndx] = $subject;
}

ksort($sortable);

var_dump($sortable);
```

`var_dump` will produce:

```
array(4) {
  ["[1"]=>
  string(6) "[1,10]"
  ["[2"]=>
  string(6) "[2,15]"
  ["[4"]=>
  string(6) "[4,16]"
  ["[6"]=>
  string(6) "[6,13]"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to use usort function :

```
$a = array([10,13],[11,15],[12,7],[1,0],[2,0],[3,0],[4,0],[5,0],[6,0],[7,0],[8,0],[9,0]);
print_r($a);
usort($a, "cmp");
print_r($a);
?>
```

See Example Here : http://ideone.com/gv4k70